# Why doesn't the variable count up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is the var idnumber inside the var newid not counting up?

```
var idnumber = 1;
var newid = "box-"+idnumber;
var newbox = "<div id='" + newid + "' class='box'></div>";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#add').click(function(){
        idnumber++;
        console.log(idnumber+" "+newid+" "+newbox);
    });
});
```

For an example see: http://jsfiddle.net/vincentweltje/jx08mwe7/

Comment: It does for me in Chrome

Comment: my console output looks like this:
 2 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 3 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 4 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 5 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 6 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 7 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 8 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 9 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>
(index):34 10 box-1 <div id='box-1' class='box'></div>

Comment: @bhspencer - The id (newid)  isn't incrementing.

Comment: Oh you want newid to increase. Not just idnumber. Sorry. You should assign a new value to newid inside you click function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you set

```
   var newid = "box-"+idnumber;
   var newbox = "<div id='" + newid + "' class='box'></div>";
```

Once, that way if you click a second time your variables won't count up.

You should put the 2 variables inside your .click function like so:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    idnumber++;
    var newid = "box-"+idnumber;
    var newbox = "<div id='" + newid + "' class='box'></div>";
    console.log(idnumber+" "+newid+" "+newbox);
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, that i haven't seen that before. Thanks